# Is the union of all $ \left[ \dfrac {1} {n},+\infty\right) $ equal to the union of all $ \left(\dfrac {1} {n},+\infty\right) $?

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

1. Consider the family $A_n = \left[ \dfrac {1} {n},+\infty\right) $,
   we have $A_{n+1}    \supset A_n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and
   the family $B_n = \left( \dfrac {1} {n},+\infty\right) $, we have
   $B_{n+1}    \supset B_n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$,  does 
   $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n $ and $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$ represent the same set ? Please give a proof !
2. In my opinion, since $A_{n}    \supset B_n$ for every    $n \in \mathbb{N}$, thus I guess
   $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n $ has more element(s) than  $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$  , but if this is true , what are the elements in  $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ but not in $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we have $B_{n+1}\supset A_n$, which means that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_{n+1}$ clearly contains $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$, by the same argument. But $B_{n+1}\supset B_n$ implies that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_{n}=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_{n+1}$ (adding $B_1$ to the union changes nothing, since anything that's in $B_1$ is also in $B_2$).

This means that the two unions are equal.

One can also argue from the definition of union: What does $x\in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_{n}$ mean? It means that there exists some $k$ such that $x\in A_k$. But clearly, this also means that $x\in B_{k+1}$, which by definition of union means that $x\in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_{n}$. Therefore $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_{n}\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_{n}$. Inclusion the other way is proven similarly (except you can get away with using the same index $k$ on $A_k$ and $B_k$).

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that $B_{n+1}\supset A_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that both sets are equal to $\{x\in\mathbb{R} \mid x\gt 0\}.$

For basically the same amount of work, you not only prove that the two sets are equal, but you find out exactly what they are.